# What am I getting wrong in this QuickSort Case?

Tags: sorting

Hey im coding quicksort atm. Im making the last element in the array my pivot. Specific case:
[7,6,8]
8 would be the pivot, 7 is low and 6 is high.
Since 7 < 8 low increases by 1. But now low and high are the same. So 6 gets switched with 8 which would make the array [7,8,6]. But it should be [6,7,8] obviously.

What am i forgetting to implement?

Comment: Follow this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/ Essentially, 7 and 8 are not suppose to switch. You should advance high one more time, and so "swaping" 8 with itself (so it remains inplace)

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, basically had to add what to do with that scenario where the low pointer goes the high pointer, without the high pointer changing.